# How does underscores.me generate files off field entries?

Tags: php, regex, generator

http://underscores.me/

I would love to accomplish something like this for our new client generation in my company. What is the method that _s uses to generate their files after regex?

For example: if I wanted to generate a new suite of files for our new client "ACME", I would enter "ACME" and this program would generate files with that populated.

Also would it be possible to create things like Excel files with these fields data?

I know it's a fairly general question, and not stackoverflow's usual way of sharing a dialogue, but I figured I'd try to get what direction I could from this.

Thank you!

Comment: so it just renames existing files?

Comment: Also changes out client names within the files. In addition to other specified standard intake fields.